# AppConKit3: Not possible to dismiss current view in onFinish Callback

Tags: javascript, appconkit

I want to achieve the following: send some data to the server and upon successful execution, dismiss the current view. 
What I've done so far:

1. Send the data via DataRequest (works)
2. Add an onFinish Callback (works)
3. Try to dimiss the current Viewcontroller in the onFinish (fails)
   Here is my code

   ```
   function sendTopic() {
    var vServerController = mobileController.serverController();
    var vJSONRequest = vServerController.createDataRequest();
    vJSONRequest.setQueryMethod("createTopic");
    vJSONRequest.setOnFinish(finish);
    vServerController.addToQueue(vJSONRequest);
   }

   function finish(vResponse) {
     if (vResponse.body().search("200")) {
       //we got a 200 back, everything worked!
       logger.showMessage("All okay!");
       mobileController.activeController().dismissModal();
     }
   }
   ```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `activeController` is not defined for callback methods, since the UI could change during the request execution.

Therefore the `solutionController` allows to find the controller you want to dismiss, using the `findFirstViewController` method.

Try this in your callback method.

```
function finish(vResponse) {
  if (vResponse.body().search("200")) {
    //we got a 200 back, everything worked!
    logger.showMessage("All okay!");
    var vControllerToDismiss = mobileController.solutionController().findFirstViewController(Screens.MyScreenToDismiss);
    if (vControllerToDismiss) {
        vControllerToDismiss.dismissModal();
    } else {
        logger.showMessage("Cant find controller named '" + Screens.MyScreenToDismiss + "'.");
    }
  }
}
```